# Find round brackets in the sentence and screen them

Tags: javascript

I need check if phrase has round brackets inside and if so, screen them
For example:
"Apple (LLC)" should be "Apple \(LLC\)"

I tried such regex for find if phrase has brackets:

```
 let reg = '\\(([^)]+)\\)';
 reg.test("Apple (LLC)")
```

but I received nothing. Can somebody help?

Comment: Use an online regex tester.  It helps a lot: https://regexr.com/

Comment: I need code solution

Comment: Teach a being to fish.  You've got too many "\"
This works -> `\(([^)]+)\)`

Comment: Wouldn't `.replace('(', '\\(')` work?

Comment: you'd probably want to verify there is no leading `\` before  adding an extra.

Answer (score 4):

This regex `/\((.*?)\)/` may help.

Demo:

```js
var text = "Apple (LLC)";

var result = text.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, "\\($1\\)");

console.log(result)
```

Comment: what if phrase don't have ()?

Comment: @rick1 Then it would replace nothing and return unchanged string

Comment: @Justinas thank you. I should better recheck replace()

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp was not strictly correct. Try this:

```
let reg=/\(([^)]+)\)/
reg.test("Apple (LLC)")
```